# Does uniform convergence imply absolute convergence for Fourier series?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, uniform-convergence, absolute-convergence

Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous $1$-periodic function. We can compute the Fourier coefficients
$$a_n := \int_0^1 f(x)\exp(-2\pi i nx) dx.$$
If
$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} |a_n| < \infty $$
it's easy to see that
$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} a_n\exp(2\pi i n x)$$
converges uniformly to $f$.

Is the opposite true as well? So does the uniform convergence of the last series imply the absolute convergence of the Fourier coefficients?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Edwards' *Fourier Series: A Modern Introduction, Volume 1*:

**Theorem 7.2.2. (1)** Suppose that $a_n\downarrow 0$ (meaning $a_n\ge 0$ is monotonically nonincreasing and $a_n\to 0$). Then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sin(nx)$ is uniformly convergent, if and only if $na_n \to 0$.

In particular, we can say that $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)}{n\log n}$ converges uniformly on an interval of length $2\pi$, but not absolutely since $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n\log n}$ diverges.

If you take the [uniform boundedness of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin nx}{n}$ on intervals of length $2\pi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3085741/evaluating-sum-n-1-infty-frac-sinnxn-without-integrating-sum-n-1) for granted, you can also give a direct proof that $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\sin(nx)}{n\log n}$ converges uniformly using the method of summation by parts.

**Added:**

> **Corollary to Theorem 7.16 in Rudin's *PMA* (paraphrased).** Suppose $f_n$ are Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, and that
> $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)\quad(a\le x\le b),$$
> the series converging uniformly on $[a,b]$. Then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, and
> $$
> \int_a^b f(x)\,dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_a^bf_n(x)\,dx.
> $$
> In other words, the series may be integrated term by term.

Note that we do not require absolute convergence of the series $\sum f_n(x)$ to integrate term by term.

Thus, for a sequence $a_n$ as in Edwards' Theorem 7.2.2. (1) and a function $f(x) = \sum a_n\sin(nx)$, the coefficients $a_n$ are the Fourier coefficients of $f(x)$:
$$
a_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin(nx)\,dx.
$$

---

Also, the [discussion in the answer and comments on this post is relevant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3165664/function-with-uniformly-but-non-absolutely-convergent-fourier-series), and in particular pointed me to the book of Edwards.

Comment: Is it clear that for uniformly converging series $f(x)=\sum a_n \sin(nx)$ the $a_n$ are just its Fourier coefficients? I think in the proof where you show that the respective integrals bring you back the $a_n$ you need to change the order of summation and integration which is only allowed when you have an absolutely converging series.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain: Good question. From the perspective of Lebesgue integration, we do usually require absolute convergence to integrate term by term. However, in this context, a function defined by the series $f(x)=\sum a_n \sin(nx)$ with $a_n$ as in Theorem 7.2.2. (1) is also Riemann integrable, and hence integrating term by term is justified by the uniform convergence of the series. I updated my answer to address this point.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your update. In your Corollary to Theorem 7.16 let's assume the $f_n$ are continuous and do not converge absolutely. Then $f$ is continuous as well so the Lebesgue integral is well definied. The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_a^bf_n(x)\,dx$ will then be the correct value of the Lebesgue integral but doesn't need to converge absolutely, right?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain: that’s right. It’s a consequence of the fact that the Riemann integral agrees with the Lebesgue integral when they both exist.